# Perform pandas concatenation of dataframe and read it from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a use case where I need to create a python dictionary with year and months and then concatenate all the dataframes to single dataframe. I have done the implementation as below:

```py
dict_year_month = {}
temp_dict_1={}
temp_dict_2={}  
for ym in [201104,201105 ... 201706]:

    key_name = 'df_'+str(ym)+'A'
        temp_dict_1[key_name]=df[(df['col1']<=ym) & (df['col2']>ym)
                                      & (df['col3']==1)]

        temp_dict_2[key_name]=df[(df['col1']<=ym) & (df['col2']==0)
                                     & (df['col3']==1)]

        if not temp_dict_1[key_name].empty:
            dict_year_month [key_name] =temp_dict_1[key_name]
            dict_year_month [key_name].loc[:, 'new_col'] = ym
        elif not temp_dict_2[key_name].empty:
            dict_year_month [key_name] =temp_dict_2[key_name]
            dict_year_month [key_name].loc[:, 'new_col'] = ym

        dict_year_month [key_name]=dict_year_month [key_name].sort_values('col4')
        dict_year_month [key_name]=dict_year_month [key_name].drop_duplicates('col5') 
   .. do some other processing 
   create individual dataframes as df_201104A .. and so on ..
dict_year_month
#concatenate all the above individual dataframe into single dataframe:
df1 = pd.concat([
           dict_year_month['df_201104A'],dict_year_month['df_201105A'],
           ... so on till dict_year_month['df_201706A'])
```

Now the challenge is I have to rerun the set of code on each quarter so every time I have to update this script with new yearmonths dict key and in `pd.concat` as well needs to updated with new year month details. I am looking for some other solution by which I can probably read the keys and create a list of dataframes in concatenate from a properties file or config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only a few things you need to do to get there - the first is just to enumerate through the months between your start and end month, which I do below using rrule, reading in the start and end dates from a file. This gets you the keys for your dictionary. Then just use the `.values()` method on the dictionaries to get all the dataframes.

```
from dateutil import rrule
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pickle

#get these from whereever, config, etc.
params = {
    'start_year':2011,
    'start_month':4,
    'end_year':2017,
    'end_month':6,
}

pickle.dump(params, open("params.pkl", "wb"))

params = pickle.load(open("params.pkl", "rb"))

start = datetime(year=params['start_year'], month=params['start_month'], day=1)
end = datetime(year=params['end_year'], month=params['end_month'], day=1)

keys = [int(dt.strftime("%Y%m")) for dt in rrule.rrule(rrule.MONTHLY, dtstart=start, until=end)]
print(keys)    
## Do some things and get a dict
dict_year_month = {'201104':pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3]]), '201105':pd.DataFrame([[4, 5, 6]])} #... etc

pd.concat(dict_year_month.values())
```

The pickle file is to show one way of saving and loading parameters - it is a binary format so manually editing the parameters wouldn't really work. You might want to investigate something like [yaml](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML) to get more sophisticated, feel free to ask a new question if you need help with that.

Comment: Thanks ken, its bit clear till keys generation but after creation of dictionary again you are hardcoding '201104' etc .. then again for next i have to come to this script to append the new years don't you think the same ?

Comment: @user07 that was just me giving some example data, that is where you will have your code for generating the dictionary of dataframes, I don't know everything you are doing so just skipped it and created a dummy thing do show how to do the `concat` at the end

Comment: Ken, is any way to create pyspark dataframe out of `dict_year_month.values()` instead of `pd.concat(dict_year_month.values())` ? assuming dict_year_month has pyspark dataframes created.